# Value not saved in designer.cs

Tags: c#, .net

I have a custom DataGridViewColumn and I want to have a custom property.

I am using the following code :

```
private bool IsShowUpDown;
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[Browsable(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Bindable(true)]
public bool ShowUpDown
{
    get
    {
        return IsShowUpDown;
    }
    set
    {
        IsShowUpDown = value;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I change the property in design-time from false to true, the change is not saved in the designer.cs file.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you describe how you're using this custom DataGridViewColumn, so we could attempt to reproduce the issue?